# Hadoop PIG Custom UDF method in foreach generate loop

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

Is it possible to code UDF function that will do following

```
records = load INPUT using PigStorage() AS (vin:chararray , longString:chararray);

simpleData = foreach records generate vin , myUdfFunctionGetValue(longString , 'someKey');
```

Here longString is of structure "key:Value;key2:Value2,someKey:Value3...."

So I need to parse longString and get the value of asked key. Am I going to wrong direction and  is this possible in PIG?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a python UDF.

**UDF:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

@outputSchema("output:chararray")
def key_value_parser(s, k):

    try:
        d = dict([x.split(':') for x in s.split(';')])
        return d[k]
    except:
        return None
```

**Pig:**

```
REGISTER '/root/path/name_of_udf.py' USING jython as udf;
data = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS (vin:chararray, longString:chararray);
parsedString = FOREACH data GENERATE udf.key_value_parser(longString, 'key3');
DUMP parsedString;
```

Assuming `longString` is of the form `key1:Value1;Key2:Value2;key3:Value3; ...`

**Output:**

```
(Value3)
```

Comment: Thank you I will test this tomorrow, never coded in python but that should not be a problem, I just need to check if our server has python installed , I will let you know  this looks promising.

Comment: Just a note that you will need to have [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) installed.  I'm assuming if you have Pig, then you have Jython.